# Opening .EDGE file in python | Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am new to complex network analysis and was tinkering with Networkx. I wanted to use a multilayer network which I got from http://deim.urv.cat/~manlio.dedomenico/data.php .
However, the file format that I am getting is **higgsData.edges.gz**. If I uncompress the file I get an .EDGES type file. Now how do I read it through python.

If I open the **higgsData.edges**, I see something like this:

```
1 0 9 1
1 0 50 1
1 0 268 1
1 0 1845 1
1 0 1940 1
```

Can somebody please show me some pointers or share some tutorials as to where should I proceed? I am clueless about this.

Thanks

Regards

Comment: How would I open a file like higgsData.edges?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same things. I think the only way is to read the file manually and import the edges one by one.

By the way, if you work with multilayer or multiplex graph you could try the following library:
http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/kivela/mln_library/index.html

In particular you can try the loader, it should takes also that kind of edges structure.